# How does generating a snapshot of a SQL Server CE database differ from simply copying the .SDF file?

Tags: sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

If I want a copy of a SQL Server CE database that is provisioned for synchronisation (and optionally contains some data already), I can make it using `SqlCeSyncStoreSnapshotInitialization`:

```
using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(sourceConnectionString))
{
    var snapshot = new SqlCeSyncStoreSnapshotInitialization();
    snapshot.GenerateSnapshot(conn, "snapshot.sdf");
}
```

How does the generated CE database differ from the original? Would it be any different if I simply made a copy of the original `.SDF` file?

Answer (score 1):

the difference is that each replica in Sync Fx gets a unique replica id. When you use a generated snapshot, this is is reset on first sync. if you simply copy the sdf, you'll end up with databases having the same replica id and will mess up the sync.

assuming you have a snapshot A with replica id 1, you copy it as B but it still has replica id 1. 
You sync A with server Z, and server Z remembers what it synched with replica id 1.

You try to sync B with Z and Z uses the metadata of what it synched with replica id 1 (A) and thinks B is A.

you're now using sync metadata for another database because can't distinguish the two.

Comment: Thanks JuneT. Are you able to describe how the sync would get messed up? BTW, I am using SyncOrchestrator. In an answer to another question you said that Snapshots don't work with SyncOrchestrator. Is that still correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be different. A snapshot is a specially-prepared SQL Server Compact database that contains table schema, data (optional), and change-tracking infrastructure. During the first synchronization session for a client, client-specific metadata is updated, and any changes that occurred since the snapshot was created are downloaded to the client database.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/microsoft.synchronization.data.sqlserverce.sqlcesyncstoresnapshotinitialization(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks ErikEJ, but the question is _how_ it differs. I've read all the online docs and nothing seems to explain it. Just copying the original .SDF file appears to work fine, so I want to know what benefit I get from making a snapshot first.